# How to change link url image from link other website?

Tags: php

I have a link from other website:

```
http://www.website1.com/image1.jpg
http://www.website2.com/image/image2.jpg
http://www.website3.com/image/url/image3.jpg
```

I want change link url from this website, for my webiste:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/image1.jpg
http://www.mywebsite.com/image2.jpg
http://www.mywebsite.com/image3.jpg
```

Can I using regular ex ? How to this ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <pre>
    <?php

    $urls = array('http://www.website1.com/image1.jpg',
                 'http://www.website2.com/image/image2.jpg',
                  'http://www.website3.com/image/url/image3.jpg'
            );
    while(list($i, $uri) = each($urls)) {
        $urls[$i] = foo($uri);

    }
    print_r($urls);

     function foo($uri) {
        $url = parse_url($uri);
        $paths = explode('/', $url['path']);
        return sprintf("%s://%s/%s", $url['scheme'], $url['host'], end($paths));
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.website1.com/image1.jpg
    [1] => http://www.website2.com/image2.jpg
    [2] => http://www.website3.com/image3.jpg
)
```

Comment: With strict error checking turned on I get `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ... on line 16`. Shouldn't be a problem, but I thought I should mention it anyway.

Comment: @Kakashi: OUTPUT this incorrect:Array
(
    [0] => http://www.mywebsite.com/image1.jpg
    [1] => http://www.mywebsite.com/image2.jpg
    [2] => http://www.mywebsite.com/image3.jpg
)

Comment: @HaiTruong: I see you found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515038/repair-link-url-mywebsite-from-other-link. It would be good form to credit Kakashi for this much of the code on that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com' + 
substr($url_from_other_website, strrpos($url_from_other_website, '/'));
```